# Set specific xml resources to Robolectric

Tags: android, android-resources, robolectric

I am running with Robolectric v2.4

I would like to access a file located on the device with Robolectric.

With Android 7 the way is a bit different to access the app local directory. I need a resource file.

The resource file is (test/res/xml/file_paths.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path name="my_images" path="Android/data/com.my.app/files/Pictures" />
</paths>
```

In my test :

```
@Test
public void testGetExternalPhotoUri() throws Exception {
    DateTime dateTime = new DateTime(2014, 1, 23, 15, 20, 30);
    File externalPhotoFile = PhotoStorageUtils.getExternalPhotoFile(dateTime, application.getApplicationContext());
    String path = FileProvider.getUriForFile(application.getApplicationContext(), "com.my.app", externalPhotoFile).getPath();
    assertThat(path).endsWith(projectCode + File.separator + "photo_20140123_152030.jpg");
}
```

I get a NPE

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.support.v4.content.FileProvider.parsePathStrategy(FileProvider.java:583)
at android.support.v4.content.FileProvider.getPathStrategy(FileProvider.java:557)
at android.support.v4.content.FileProvider.getUriForFile(FileProvider.java:399)
at com.my.app.core.util.PhotoStorageUtilsTest.testGetInternalPhotoCompressedFile(PhotoStorageUtilsTest.java:50)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$2.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:236)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$1.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:158)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:117)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:42)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:262)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:84)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
```

and we can understand that the NPE is thrown by PhotoStorageUtils.getExternalPhotoFile().

I guess this is because my path_files.xml is not read.

How can I set the xml file to Robolectric ?
Thanks

**---- EDIT ----**

See also : https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/issues/2199

Still not solved my problem... :(